# How to restrict access to symbols in shared object?

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, symbols

I have a plug-in in the form of a shared library (bar.so) that links into a larger program (foo). Both foo and bar.so depend on the same third party library (baz) but they need to keep their implementations of baz completely separate. So when I link foo (using the supplied object files and archives) I need it to ignore any use of baz in bar.so and vice versa.

Right now if I link foo with `--trace-symbol=baz_fun` where baz_fun is one of the offending symbols I get the following output:

```
bar.so: definition of baz_fun
foo/src.a(baz.o): reference to baz_fun
```

I believe this is telling me that foo is referencing baz_fun from bar.so (and execution of foo confirms this).

Solutions that I have tried:

- Using `objcopy` to "localize" the symbols of interest: `objcopy --localize-symbols=local.syms bar.so` where local.syms contains all of the symbols of interest. I think I might just be confused here and maybe "local" doesn't mean what I think it means. Regardless, I get the same output from the link above. I should note that if I run the `nm` tool on bar.so prior to using `objcopy` all of the symbols in question have the `T` flag (upper-case indicating global) and after `objcopy` they have a `t` indicating they are local now. So it appears I am using `objcopy` correctly.
- Compiling with `-fvisibility=hidden` however due to some other constraints I need to use GCC 3.3 which doesn't appear to support that feature. I might be able to upgrade to a newer version of GCC but would like confirmation that compiling with this flag will help me before heading down that road.

Other things to note:

- I do not have access to the source code of either foo or baz
- I would prefer to keep all of my plug-in in one shared object (bar.so). baz is actually a licensing library so I don't want it separated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `dlopen` to load your plugin with `RTLD_DEEPBIND` flag.

(edit)

Please note that RTLD_DEEPBIND is Linux-specific and need glibc 2.3.4 or newer.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but how can I do this if I don't have access to the source code of foo which loads my plugin, bar.so?

Comment: Ok if you only control bar and not foo, you can split bar in two libraries, bar1 and bar2. bar1 provides the plugin interface and forwards all calls to bar2, and bar2 implements everything. bar1 should call `dlopen("libbar2.so",RTLD_NOW|RTLD_DEEPBIND)` and `dlsym` all functions it needs. Or you could keep one bar, and `dlopen("libbaz.so",RTLD_NOW|RTLD_DEEPBIND)` from there, and `dlsym` all functions you need. Use whichever method needs fewer calls to `dlsym`.